# blocking directing linking to php script with .htaccess instead of using php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to use .htaccess to block access to a form action php script. I would rather use .htaccess access instead of sessions  or any programming method in php. Is there anyway to block direct access to submit.php form action script with .htaccess?

Comment: yes, but putting it outside the web root is a better idea

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourotherdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(form.php)$ - [F]
```